# TFS 'when' and 'required' rules does not set the field to required

Tags: tfs-workitem, tfs-process-template

I have a custom field (fixedInVersion), the field is required when `state = 'Closed'`.

I also have a custom control for the field (combo with sorting, because the default sorting of TFS control is ascending).

When the work Item state is `Closed`, I display in my control `Required` but the user can still save the work item without getting error.

Does anyone knows what is the problem?
If I remove the text `Required` the item cannot be saved, but the only indication for the user is that the combo is yellow (no text `Required` is displayed).

Answer (score 0):

The "When" Required value, did you use it? see the following example:

```
<FieldDefinition refname="fixedInVersion" name="fixedInVersion" type="String">
  <WHEN field="System.State" value="Closed">
    <REQUIRED />
  </WHEN>
</FieldDefinition>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I did, and the fixedInVersion is required when state is Closed. But after the work item is saved with fixedInVersion value I can delete it (it's not really required)